# Directory of files containerized and deployed in Lambda?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, docker, aws-lambda

I have a Python package directory for which looks like this:

[image]

I have a Dockerfile which uses AWS provided base image:

```
COPY requirements.txt .
RUN pip install --upgrade pip
ENV LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT="/usr/lambda"
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt --target "${LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT}"
COPY src/b "${LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT}"
```

Now when I deploy a lambda using image built using code above, and I use "b.handler.lambda_handler" as my CMD override, I get this error:

```
Unable to import module 'b': No module named 'b'
```

I have tried using CMD override "handler.lambda_handler", but that gives me a similar error.

If my code has multiple files like so, can I not copy entire directory and then call my handler ?
Can someone point me to right solution or documentation ? AWS seems to have a documentation which guides me through a 1-file setup only.

EDIT 1:
When I run image locally, I get this:

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> docker run -p 9000:8080 3cdde6464b082779fec0f6c263b9052514886d4f90d0d0c1a6d8d40f459660c7
12 Apr 2023 23:10:34,654 [INFO] (rapid) exec '/var/runtime/bootstrap' (cwd=/var/task, handler=)
```

Comment: you may try to set [`workdir`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#workdir) in `Dockerfile` (WORKDIR /usr/lambda). Also try to temporary run container without `ENV`s (set `/usr/lambda` in all lines manually). It may help to understand the problem root.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution was to remove following line from Dockerfile.

```
ENV LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT="/usr/lambda"
```